# three horizontal squares |square| |square| |square| using css

Tags: css

I was trying to display the squares (like bullet squares)using

```
   .squares{
     list-style-type: square;
     display:inline;
    }
```

but I want them horizontally instead of vertical bullet squares Is there any way I could get 3 squares?

Comment: You need to do inline on the `li`.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried doing?

Comment: Try this resource, then come back and show exactly what you have tried: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/

Comment: When you change the `display` to `inline` the `list-style-type` won't work. You would probably be better off using `float: left` (like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jLgopybe/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since setting the display of a list item to `inline` causes it to stop prepending the bullets, you can't use the usual `list-style-type` method.

@Aibrean avoided it by using float to inline the items. This gets a bit ugly ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnuw58c0/)), because different layout rules apply to `float`ed elements. This can be solved by using [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix), but there's an easier mothod of doing this:

```
.squares > li{
 display: inline;
}

.squares > li:before{
 content: "\25A0  "; /* Square and space */
}
```

This prepends content to each `li` in css. `254A` is the [unicode encoding for a solid square](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a0/index.htm)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/854jLtzx/)

---

If you just want 3 squares in you content, you may find it easier just using the html unicode entities for squares directly in html:

```
&#x25a0; &#x25a0; &#x25a0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z1ye0or4/

Comment: NP, Did you go for the HTML solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use the list item element to align horizontally.

```
 ul.squares{
     list-style-type:square;      
 }

 .squares li {
     float:left;
     margin-right:10px;
 }
```

Now use the class appropriately:

```
<ul class="squares">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
<ul>
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7t82L1dh/